# How can I "disable/enable" my laptop's touchpad on Elementary OS Loki?

Tags: settings, touchpad, release-loki

How I can "disable/enable" my laptop's touchpad on Elementary OS 0.4 Loki?

Comment: I switched for a couple of days from freya to loki and unhappily your right. In freya it was possible to switch off the touchpad and in the mouse-system-settings of loki it isn't anymore :(

Comment: partially answered [here](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/326/170). I have added that answer under here and more on how to use shortcuts

Answer (score 8):

Do `xinput list` to see the **name** of the touchpad. Let's say it's **"SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"**.

[image]

(the number after `id=` can be used instead of the name of the device, but id may vary between systems and can even be changed after reboot in some cases. Using the name is safer, as the wrong id can disable the keyboard, etc)

The command to disable would then be

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 0
```

Enable:

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 1
```

**Change accordingly to YOUR device name.**

These two commands can then be associated with shortcuts under *Keyboard > Custom > Add*

[image]

These two commands can also be run through the Applications launcher:

Having Gedit as text editor:

```
sudo gedit ~/.local/share/applications/disable_touchpad.desktop
```

With the lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Disable touchpad
Comment=Set your touchpad preferences
Exec= xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 0
Icon=touchpad-disabled
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;HardwareSettings;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;System;
```

Also:

```
sudo gedit ~/.local/share/applications/enable_touchpad.desktop
```

With the lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Enable touchpad
Comment=Set your mouse and touchpad preferences
Exec= xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 1
Icon=input-touchpad-symbolic
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;HardwareSettings;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;System;
```

Now, just use the Super-Space launcher and type the first letters of 'touchpad', 'enable' or 'disable'.

[image]

Once created, those launchers can be accessed in different ways, like added to the dock etc.

Comment: Thanks! A little correction to others `Icon=touchpad-disabled` must be `Icon=touchpad-disabled-symbolic`.

Comment: Also my mouse ID changes at every restart. I've handled by using `Exec= xinput set-prop "my device name" "Device Enabled" 0`.

Comment: @efkan - Concerning icons: both work for me. I can confirm I have the line `Icon=touchpad-disabled` in `/usr/share/applications/disable_touchpad.desktop`

Comment: @efkan - Concerning touchpad ID (not the *mouse* ID): that seems very useful and should be used instead of the number. - Please tell me what should I put for ""my device name" considering the `xinput list` results?

Comment: You should put "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" instead of ID (should be included double quotes). Your solution is really useful for me.

Comment: @efkan - I will add that to the answer.

Comment: I recommend adding `xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 0` command to the startup and to your answer. This is really useful ;)

Comment: For those using Apple hardware, don't use "Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad" as the device name. That will only disable the keyboard, not the Trackpad. Have yet to find the name of the actual Trackpad

Comment: Should use `sudo -e` instead of `sudo gedit`

Comment: @red_trumpet - `should`? You mean `may`. But thanks for bringing me back to this post of mine: what needs to be changed is the whole need for sudo. I will change the answer, using only `~/.local/share/applications` for new desktop files is safer, cleaner, quicker.

Answer (score 0):

If your keybinding is not working you can try typing in terminal *"synclient TouchPadOff=1"* command in order to disable touchpad if you want to enable it back you can type *"synclient TouchpadOff=0"*

Comment: `synclient TouchPadOff=1` gives me this: `Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?` and has no other effect.

Comment: Okay then can you first type in terminal "xinput list" then seek for your touchpad id then type in "xinput set-prop #id "Device Enabled" 0"  replace #id with the id of your touchpad

Comment: I am the OP of the answer that already says that.

Comment: @cipricus sorry I didnt check that the case I have told first was for the case where you use synaptics package sorry if I couldnt help

Comment: Don't  worry. - I have made a change to my answer (according to a new comment) that is independent of the variable number of the device id and uses instead the name of the device. - You mean your solution works on machines that do not use synaptics? What does it show for you under `xinput list`? (just curious)

Comment: The synclient method works if synaptics packages are installed the second method is what you have proposed. I didn't get what you are asking? I am on mobile now I cant post the xinput output but I remember that was something similar to your output

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do in my elementary os (0.3 Freya). Hope this will help, since 0.4 Freya is based on Ubuntu 16.04

Go to all settings -> Mouse & Touchpad -> Touchpad

And turn off touchpad

Comment: Thanks but There is not an option the "turn off touchpad" in the Mouse & Touchpad settings.

Comment: it's not an option, it's a button, simply turn it off

Comment: Thanks again but there is not a button, an option or a choice the "turn off touchpad" in the Mouse & Touchpad settings.

Comment: In Loki that button seems absent